# creating a cost function in jgrapht

Tags: jgrapht

jgrapht supports the idea of putting a wehight(a cost) on an edge/vertex between two nodes. This can be achieved using the class DefaultWeightedEdge.

In my graph I do have the requirement to not find the shortest path but the cheapest one. The cheapest path might be longer/have more hops nodes to travel then the shortest path.
Therefor, one can use the DijkstraShortestPath algorithm to achieve this.

However, my use case is a bit more complex: It needs to also evaluate costs on actions that need to be executed when arriving at a node.

Let's say, you have a graph like a chess board(8x8 fields, each field beeing a node). All the edges have a weight of 1. To move in a car from left bottom to the diagonal corner(right upper), there are many paths with the cost of 16. You can take a diagonal path in a zic zac style, or you can first travel all nodes to the right and then all nodes upwards.
The difference is: When taking a zic zac, you need to rotate yourself in the direction of moving. You rotate 16 times.
When moving first all to the right and then upwards, you need to rotate only once (maybe twice, depending on your start orientation).
So the zic zac path is, from a Djikstra point of view, perfect. From a logical point of view, it's the worst.

Long story short: How can I put some costs on a node or edge depending on the previous edge/node in that path? I did not find anything related in the source code of jgrapht.
Or is there a better algorithm to use?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a JGraphT issue but a graph algorithm issue. You need to think about how to encode this problem and formalize that in more detail

1. Incorporating weights on vertices is in general easy. Say that every vertex represents visiting a customer, which takes a_i time. This can be encoded in the graph by adding a_i/2 to the cost of every incoming arc in node i, as well as a_i/2 to the cost of every outgoing arc.
2. A cost function where the cost of traveling from j to k dependents on the arc (i,j) you used to travel to j is more complicated.

Approach a.: Use a dynamic programming (labeling) algorithm. This is perhaps the easiest. You can define your cost function as a recursive function, where the cost of traversing an arc depends on the cost of the previous arc.

Approach b.: With some tricks you may be able to encode the costs in the graph by adding extra nodes to it. Here's an example:

Given a graph with vertices {a,b,c,d,e}, with arcs: (a,e), (e,b), (c,e), (e,d). This graph represents a crossroad with vertex e being in the middle. Going from a->e->b (straight) is free, however, a turn from a->e->d takes additional time. Similar for c->e->d (straight) is free and c->e->b (turning) should be penalized.
Decouple vertex e in 4 new vertices: e1,e2,e3,e4.
Add the following arcs:
(a,e1), (e3,b), (c,e2), (e4,d), (e2, e3), (e1, e3), (e1, e4), (e2, e4).
(e1,e4) and (e2,e3) can have a positive weight to penalize turning.

Comment: My comment regarding JGraphT was more in the direction if it supports this without me doing some exploding of the graph explicitly.
I came up with a similar idea as your approach b. However I am not sure how bad this influences the performance of the Djikstra. We do have 11'000 arcs in that graph already. The graph is somewhat a static grid. So worst case we generate out of 4 arcs up to 30 new arcs. So we roughly end up with 80'000 arcs.

Approach a: does jgrapht ship some labeling algorithms? I did not find an overview about supported algorithms except what's in javadoc

Comment: My advise would be to just give it a try. Don't optimize something that is 'fast enough' for your application. If you need to perform a few shortest path calculations, then Dijkstra may be sufficient. Alternatively, you could try to use A* search, which uses an admissible heuristic. That may be faster if your data has a particular structure. Your checkboard example would be trivially solved by A*. If you need a lot of shortest path calculations, and your graph doesn't change, consider using FloydWarshallShortestPaths to calculate all shortest paths in bulk.

Comment: JGraphT currently doesn't have a labeling algorithm since such an implementation is usually rather application specific. However, implementing a labeling algorithm isn't hard. Have a look at the book Network Flows: Theory, Algorithms, and Applications by Ahuja, Magnanti , Orlin for a high-level description of a label-setting algorithm. .

Comment: I already started working on a trial for a similar approach like your b approach. The A* might actually work as we do have a grid so the heuristic should work. Thanks for mentioning the FloydWarshall, I'll check this one. Unfortunately, the graph is manipulated many times to track blocked nodes. But maybe still I can reuse some of it. The book sounds interesting. Thanks.